# Laravel: cannot insert into many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

i hope you're having a good day.

so i have this `ManyToMany` relationship where a user can apply to multiple jobs, and a job can have multiple applicants (users).

here is the table schema

```php
        Schema::create('applicant_job', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('applicant_id');

            $table->unique(['job_id', 'applicant_id']);


            $table->foreign('job_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('jobs')
                ->onDelete('cascade');


            $table->foreign('applicant_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('default_users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

and here is the model code.

`DefaultUser.php`

```php
class DefaultUser extends Model
{
  
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
    }

    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class, 'applicant_job', 'job_id', 'applicant_id');
    }
}
```

and `Job.php`

```php
class Job extends Model
{
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BusinessUser::class, 'business_user_id');
    }

    public function applicants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DefaultUser::class, 'applicant_job', 'applicant_id', 'job_id');
    }
}
```

everything seems ok and find, however when i try to save ( a user applying to a job), i get the following error
[image]

i'm doing so inside `ApplyToJobController.php`

```php
class ApplyToJobController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Job $job, Request $request) {
        $default_user = auth()->user()->userable;

        $job->applicants()->attach($default_user->id);

        return redirect("/en");
    }
}
```

and, **Thank you very much for your answers**.

**EDIT**

i have changed the column names to this

```
Schema::create('applicant_job', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('default_user_id');

            $table->unique(['job_id', 'default_user_id']);


            $table->foreign('job_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('jobs')
                ->onDelete('cascade');


            $table->foreign('default_user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('default_users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

it made it work, im curios any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch the order of the foreign keys in the applicants relation declared in the Job model like the example below :

```
public function applicants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(DefaultUser::class, 'applicant_job', 'job_id', 'applicant_id');
}
```

Comment: that worked successfully, any idea why this happened?

Comment: It is related to the order of the arguments of the belongToMany method, try to verify the signature of it in the HasRelationships trait